# Existence of very ample divisors on a projective surface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the proof of Castelnuovo's contractibility criterion ( Hartshorne's  Algebraic geometry). In the proof, he claim that  there must be a very ample divisor $H$ on a projective surface $X$ such that $H^1(X,\mathscr L(H))=0$.

By Serre's theorem

> Let $X$ be a projective scheme over a noetherian ring $A$, $\mathcal O_X(1)$  a very ample invertible sheaf on $X$ over $Spec A$ , and  $\mathscr F$  a coherent sheaf on $X$. 
>   Then there is an integer $n_0$ such that for each $ i>0 $ and each $n\geqslant n_0$, $H^i(X,\mathscr F(n))=0$

Here $X$ is a projective surface over an algebraically closed field $\mathrm k$, a divisor $H$ corresponds to an invertible sheaf $\mathscr L(H)$, so, does he use $\mathscr L(H)\otimes_{\mathcal O_X}\mathcal O_X(n)\cong \mathscr L(nH)$ to give that claim ? I am not sure. But why we have this isomorphism ? Thank you!

Comment: We can take $H$ to be the divisor corresponding to the invertible sheaf $\mathcal O_X(n)$ for a large enough $n$.

Comment: @danneks  Let $\mathscr F=\mathcal O_X$,$H=\mathscr F(n)=\mathcal O_X\otimes_{\mathcal O_X} \mathcal O_X(n)\cong \mathcal O_X(n)$ for a sufficiently large $n$?

Comment: Yes, the theorem says that higher cohomology of this sheaf are zero.

Comment: @danneks thank you